# Migrating MySQL 8.0.20 database to AWS Aurora

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I was trying to use the [AWS RDS Proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/) service and realized that the only [compatible versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.AuroraFeaturesRegionsDBEngines.grids.html#Concepts.Aurora_Fea_Regions_DB-eng.Feature.RDS_Proxy) with the service are AWS Aurora.

The current database I have is a MySQL database using MySQL version 8.0.20. AWS Aurora is MySQL compatible but only with version 5.6 and 5.7. I am not overly familiar with these versions and how different it would be to version 8.0.20.

Has anyone gone through the process of converting a MySQL database to Aurora? I know there are [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Migrating.RDSMySQL.Import.html) on the subject out there but they deal with version 5.6 or 5.7, has anyone done it for later versions?

I have all the MySQL code in SQL files along with the stored procedures so the database creation can be automated to an extent, it would just be if anyone has ran into issues doing it/found a better way than running multiple SQL files to transfer over data.

If you have gone through the process are there major differences between MySQL and Aurora in terms of running stored procedures etc?

Comment: That feels like a question for https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Maurice thanks I didn't know about this!

Comment: You might want to look at the RDS MySQL Proxy documentation, not the Aurora MySQL Proxy documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-proxy.html

Comment: Hi @deceze, yeah I had a read already if you go to the Planning for and setting up RDS Proxy and then the sub topic Limits for RDS Proxy one of the points is "You can't use RDS Proxy with RDS for MySQL 8.0." so the database I have at the moment is out of the question

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8 is now supported in AWS Aurora: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-aurora-mysql-3-with-mysql-8-0-compatibility-is-now-generally-available/

They include the migration path in particular through a read replica promotion or full snapshot restore from rds into aurora.

Answer (score 0):

Aurora 3.01.00 is the first public GA version of Aurora MySQL 8 released 2021-11-18 -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.3010.html

I've written a full tutorial of the upgrade process including the multiple options for pre-checks to ensure maximum compatibility at  https://github.com/ronaldbradford/aws-tutorial/blob/main/rds/mysql-aurora-major-upgrade.md

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.